# Can I have a link automatically download a file in an email?

Tags: html, file, email

I have an email with a link to a video file stored on a cloud hosting service (backblaze)

I'm trying to make it so that when someone can clicks the link the file would start to download. Right now I have this:

```
<a href="https://f000.backblazeb2.com/file/Folder/video.mp4" download="video">Download Here</a>
```

That takes you to the video instead of downloading the file. I'd like to avoid that if possible and have the link prompt you to start downloading the file when you click on it.

Is this possible to do in an email when the file is stored on a server somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't do this in plain html.
Since you can't use JavaScript in email, the best option would be to manage to include some PHP script in the server that do the job.

This example was taken from [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/316814/php-serve-a-file-for-download-without-providing-the-direct-link)
**PHP**

```
?php
// We'll be outputting a MP4
header('Content-type: video/mp4');

// It will be called downloaded.mp4
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.mp4"');

// Add your file source here 
readfile('original.mp4');
?>
```

Comment: That's great, thanks Miguel. Looks like that should do what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm happy to read that! Please mark it as accepted answer when you make sure it's useful to you.